# No CRL in certificates nowadays?

Tags: ssl

Recently, I knew about the CRL and also for that is a traditional way.

I tried to see what it is, install `fetch-crl` from ubuntu package and run, but only an error in result:

```sh
ERROR No trust anchor metadata for openssl in '/etc/grid-security/certificates/'
```

Where can I see CRLs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the fetch-crl tool is not for regular WebPKI certificates used by websites – it's for IGTF Grid certificates used by scientific computing clusters. They use the same *type* of X.509 certificate but are a different "world" from WebPKI, with different CAs, different policies, different goals. (A lot of "Grid" certificates identify clients, i.e. *people,* rather than servers.)

The fetch-crl tool expects you to have [the IGTF cert bundle](https://dist.igtf.net/distribution/current/) installed on your system, looking for the `*.crl_url` configuration files. But you can manually download the CRLs if you just want to look at them; here are a few URLs:

- http://ca.dutchgrid.nl/dcaroot/g1/crl/crl.crl
- http://crl4.digicert.com/TERENAeScienceSSLCA3.crl
- http://cafiles.cern.ch/cafiles/crl/CERN%20Root%20Certification%20Authority%202.crl

(A lot of them will be empty.)

Now as for the "regular" SSL certificates used by websites, there's no single "fetch all CRLs" tool, but you can still download individual CRLs by getting their URLs from the website's certificate.

For example, I visited a website that uses a certificate from Sectigo CA, and its certificate details have a "CRL Distribution Points" section with this URL:

- http://crl.sectigo.com/SectigoRSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crl

This one does have some "revoked certificate" entries, but they're fairly boring: just a list of serial numbers and corresponding revocation dates. You can use the `openssl` tool to show the file's contents:

```
$ openssl crl -in SectigoRSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crl -inform DER -noout -text

Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
        Last Update: Apr 20 22:50:13 2022 GMT
        Next Update: Apr 27 22:50:13 2022 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:17:D9:D6:25:27:67:F9:31:C2:49:43:D9:30:36:44:8C:6C:A9:4F:EB
            X509v3 CRL Number: 
                1321
Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: D0C7B88A7392E71180B6D05FEDFED46D
        Revocation Date: Jan 21 08:57:02 2020 GMT
    Serial Number: DE6B552000A0C234809A63E979533926
        Revocation Date: Jan 21 08:58:02 2020 GMT
    Serial Number: C1C7CA37C6C07CE16B20DF2046593D2B
        Revocation Date: Jan 22 21:00:47 2020 GMT
    [...]
```

But some WebPKI CAs in fact *don't* have CRLs anymore. For example, the *Let's Encrypt* CA relies on OCSP and short certificate lifetimes; ther is no CRL URL in the certificate used by superuser.com.

Comment: > its certificate details have a "CRL Distribution Points" section with this URL
It helps me. I can find URIs of CRL now and clearly get that CRLs are not included in a certificate themselves but as its URIs.

Comment: Well, the CRLs themselves can't be included in the certificate because they need to be updated independently – revocation happens _long after_ the certificate has been issued. (However, take a look at "OCSP stapling".)